# How can we find a generating set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

How can we find a generating set of the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}$ that does not contain the basis which is $\{1\}$ ?

I saw in my notes that such a set is the $\{2,3\}$. Why is this a generating set of $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but something like $\{-1\}$ should work?

Comment: I saw in my notes that such a set is the $\{2,3\}$. Why is this a generating set of $\mathbb{Z}$ ? @Hayden

Comment: I assume that "generating set" in this context means that every element of $\mathbb{Z}$ can be written as a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of elements of the generating set.  Since we can write $3+(-1)2=1$, by scaling this linear combination we get any integer.

Comment: I understand!!This set doesn't contain the basis, because it doesn't contain the element $1$ ? Or have I understood it wrong? @Hayden

Comment: That was my assumption, yes.

Comment: Ah ok... Thank you!! :-) Suppose we have the set $\{2\}$. Can we extend this to a basis? @Hayden

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Do you see how to generate $1$ using $2$ and $3$? That is, do you see how to write $1$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of $2$ and $3$? If so, do you see why this means that $\{2, 3\}$ spans?

Comment: I understand!!This set doesn't contain the basis, because it doesn't contain the element $1$ ? Or have I understood it wrong?

Comment: @MaryStar I think that's correct, yes.

Comment: Ah ok... Thank you!! :-) Suppose we have the set $\{2\}$. Can we extend this to a basis?

Comment: @MaryStar What is your definition of "basis" in this context? $\{2, 3\}$ is a minimal generating set, but it is not a generating set of *minimal size*.